# Java Applet get file outside JAR

Tags: java, xml, applet, inputstream, japplet

I need to get configuration file for my java applet (jes it's japplet (located on remote apache server):)) from outside JAR (file will change or be generated dynamically).

Is it possible to do this using getResourceAsStream? Or should I go another way?

This is part of my code:

```
        final MySwingMetawidget metawidget = new MySwingMetawidget();
        InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/package/metawidget-metadata.xml");
        metawidget.setInspector(new XmlInspector(new XmlInspectorConfig().setInputStream(inputStream)));
        metawidget.setConfig("/com/package/config.xml");
        metawidget.setPath("Elements");
```

And It's working when xml files are in JAR file. How can I move them outside JAR?
Can getResourceAsStream get files outside jar? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
InputStream inputStream = 
       new URL(getCodeBase(), "/com/package/metawidget-metadata.xml").openStream();
```

See [`Applet.getCodeBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29).